# Vue && mapbox- rendering component in <script> tag

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add HTML popup to Mapbox in Vue project.
This is my MapComponent.Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id='map'></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
import StarRating from 'vue-star-rating'
export default {
....
  methods: {
...
   createMap: function () {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWxleC1wZXRyb3YiLCJhIjoiY2o3dGluZTl2NGh1bjMzbnVqYjA1dnc5cCJ9.6is8d4d-BwwVlT0rPcuU1Q'
      this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: {
          ...
        },
        center: [-114.3393270, 48.4210780],
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 15,
        zoom: 5
      })

      // disable map rotation using right click + drag
      this.map.dragRotate.disable()

      // disable map rotation using touch rotation gesture
      this.map.touchZoomRotate.disableRotation()

      this.$store.state.trails.forEach((trail) => this.addMarker(trail))
    },
   addMarker: function (trail) {
      // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div')
      el.className = 'marker'

      // var content = this.popupContent(trail)
      // create the popup
      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
      .setHTML(<StarRating />)

      // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(trail.elements[14].data.point.split(','))
      .setPopup(popup)
      .addTo(this.map)
    }
...
  },
  components: {
    StarRating
  }
}
</script>
```

I got this error.

```
ReferenceError: h is not defined
    at VueComponent.addMarker (MapComponent.vue?70f3:101)
    at VueComponent.boundFn [as addMarker] (vue.esm.js?65d7:179)
    at eval (MapComponent.vue?70f3:92)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.createMap (MapComponent.vue?70f3:92)
    at VueComponent.boundFn [as createMap] (vue.esm.js?65d7:180)
    at eval (MapComponent.vue?70f3:54)
    at <anonymous>
```

An error has occurred in this code.

```
// create the popup
      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
      .setHTML(<StarRating />)
```

I am trying to search for this error but I didn't get any answer yet.
Is there anyone who has experience with this error?
How can I get rendered HTML code of StarRating Component in Script?
Thanks.